# Clojure -- what is the correct way to apply functions in sequence to an argument?

Tags: clojure

I'm not clear on the difference between `->` and `->>` in Clojure: from the [API reference](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/-%3E), it seems like the latter would be the correct way to apply several functions in sequence, i.e. *(->> x h g f)* would result in *f(g(h(x)))*.

This is related to how Lisp-like language differentiate *f(x, y)* and *(f(x))(y)*, whereas Haskell does not, correct? (Using math notation; commas intended to imply n-ary functions, not tupling).

Thanks in advance!

#### Edit

I'm wrong, neither work except on simple functions like (def inc #(+ 1 %)), where they both work.

Here's an example of a function that doesn't work with `->` or `->>`,

```
(defn mkinc­ [amnt­] (fn [x] (+ x amnt)­))
(-> 3 (mkin­c 2))
; ERROR -- Wrong number of args (2) passed to: sandbox58780$fn--58797$mkinc
((mkinc 2) 3)
; 5
```

Comment: P.S. what is the proper tag to signify a "beginner" / "newbie" question?

Comment: the proper way is not to use such tags.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`->` and `->>` are equivalent if all the functions take only one argument. Otherwise, `->` passes the value being threaded as the *first* argument to the function where as `->>` passes it as the *last* argument. The following example should make this clear:

```
(-> x
    (f 1 2)
    (g 3 4)
    (h 5 6))
```

becomes

```
(h (g (f x
         1 2)
      3 4)
   5 6)
```

or `h(g(f(x, 1, 2), 3, 4), 5, 6)`

```
(->> x
     (f 1 2)
     (g 3 4)
     (h 5 6))
```

becomes

```
(h 5 6
   (g 3 4
      (f 1 2 x)))
```

or `h(5, 6, g(3, 4, f(1, 2, x)))`

**Edit**: (Responding to the *Edit* in the question, copying this from the comments).

The example doesn't work because the `->` macro inserts the 3 as the first arg of `mkinc`.
See `(macroexpand-1 '(-> 3 (mkinc 2)))` to understand this better.

This does work: `(-> 3 ((mkinc 2)))`.
See `(macroexpand-1 '(-> 3 ((mkinc 2))))` to understand why.

Comment: Thanks very much. Is there a function for what I want, or should I just write it myself (see my answer)?

Comment: Since you seem to have single argument functions, you could just do `(-> x h g f)`. Anything that prevents you from doing this?

Comment: It doesn't work for your example because the `->` macro inserts the `3` as the first arg of `mkinc`; see `(macroexpand-1 '(-> 3 (mkinc 2)))` to understand this better.

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comment, I was about to add "@" so it showed up in your inbox. Thanks very much!

Comment: This does work: `(-> 3 ((mkinc 2)))`; see `(macroexpand-1 '(-> 3 ((mkinc 2))))` to understand why.

Answer (score 3):

-> inserts the prev form into the 2nd position. Whereas ->> inserts into the last position. Taking a page from Joy of Clojure, note the insertion point marked by `,,,`

```
(-> x (f ,,, 1) (g ,,, 2) (h ,,, 3))

(->> x (f 1 ,,,) (g 2 ,,,) (h 3 ,,,))
```

Answer (score 1):

In case there's no solution, I managed to hack it with syntax macros,

```
(defmacro fwcomp [& fcns] `(comp ~@(reverse fcns)))
(defmacro |> [x & fcns] `((fwcomp ~@fcns) ~x))
```

Usage:

```
(|> x h g f) ; equal to f(g(h(x)))
```

Comment: It's called `comp`. `((comp h g f) x)`

Comment: yeah that's regular (backwards) composition, you really want `((comp f g h) x)`.

Comment: You can also do define `|>` with a function. Renamed to `thrush`: `(defn thrush [x & fcns] (reduce #(%2 %1) x fcns))`